# App only works if I manually step-into; Otherwise exception

Tags: java, android

```
static Organizer org = new Organizer();
static {

    // Add 3 sample items.
    addItem(new DummyItem("1", org.GetArticles().get(0)[0]));
    addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Item 2"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Item 3"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("4", "Item 4"));
}
```

and in Organizer.java

```java
public class Organizer {
XMLGettersSetters data;
ArrayList<String[]> articles = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public ArrayList<String[]> GetArticles(){
    new getTask().execute("http://www.ynet.co.il/Iphone/0,13257,MainCategory-V7-2,00.xml");
    return articles;
    }

    private class getTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String[]>> {
    //AsyncTask
    }
}
```

It returns a ExceptionInInitializerError exception. What is it? 
From what I've understood it's probably got something to do with the static dummyContent.

When I debug, there's the option to do this step by step, and if I step into the new getTask().execute() everything works fine. But ONLY if I step into. Otherwise there's this exception.

EDIT: Added logcat.

```
10-05 16:49:37.099: D/dalvikvm(1959): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-05 16:49:37.189: W/ActivityThread(1959): Application com.example.newsnow is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-05 16:49:37.199: I/System.out(1959): Sending WAIT chunk
10-05 16:49:37.739: I/dalvikvm(1959): Debugger is active
10-05 16:49:37.799: I/System.out(1959): Debugger has connected
10-05 16:49:37.799: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:37.999: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:38.199: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:38.399: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:38.599: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:38.799: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:38.999: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:39.199: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:39.399: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:39.599: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:39.799: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:39.999: I/System.out(1959): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-05 16:49:40.199: I/System.out(1959): debugger has settled (1491)
10-05 16:49:44.959: W/dalvikvm(1959): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/newsnow/dummy/DummyContent;

10-05 16:49:48.099: D/AndroidRuntime(1959): Shutting down VM
10-05 16:49:48.099: W/dalvikvm(1959): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a8d930)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.example.newsnow.ItemListFragment.onCreate(ItemListFragment.java:89)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.example.newsnow.ItemListActivity.onCreate(ItemListActivity.java:59)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.example.newsnow.dummy.DummyContent.<clinit>(DummyContent.java:32)
10-05 16:49:48.139: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExceptionInInitializerError` is happening because you're trying to access the first element of an empty list, and you're doing so from a static initializer block (`static { ... }`).

It looks like you're expecting the `GetArticles` function to fetch *and immediately return* a set of articles, but that isn't how `AsyncTask` works. When you call

```
new getTask().execute("http://...");
```

a background thread is started, and it runs your `doInBackground()` method to fetch the articles. When you use the debugger, the background thread has plenty of time to finish and populate your `articles` field before you try to use it. If you run the program normally, though, the background thread doesn't have time to finish before `GetArticles()` returns. Once it returns, you call

`get(0)[0]`

on the (empty) `ArrayList` that was returned. It throws an exception because the list is empty.

The way to handle this is to override `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask`:

```
private class getTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String[]>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String[]> doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Fetch your articles...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String[]> newArticles) {
        // This runs on the UI thread
        articles = newArticles;

        // Refresh the list of articles...
        refreshArticles();
    }
}
```

The `onPostExecute()` method will run automatically when the `doInBackground()` method finish its work, and it also runs on the UI thread. This means that you can safely modify UI widgets, work with `View`s, etc. It's a good time and place to refresh the list that you're displaying to the user.

**EDIT**:

The `refreshArticles()` method should update the UI to display the articles that were just loaded. (There are other ways to do this, but the key idea is that `onPostExecute()` should notify the rest of the app that there is fresh data available.)

Be sure to remove the call to `GetArticles()` from the static initializer so that your dummy items aren't trying to make slow network requests. I would simplify `GetArticles()` as follows:

```
public void GetArticles() {
    new getTask().execute("http://www.ynet.co.il/Iphone/0,13257,MainCategory-V7-2,00.xml");
}
```

Then, when you're ready to refresh the UI, simply call `GetArticles()` and wait for `onPostExecute()` to notify you that new articles are available.

Comment: I tried doing this and it didn't work. Or maybe I just misunderstood - What does refreshArticles() do? present the just loaded articles?

Comment: Updated my answer. If it still doesn't work, please edit your question to include the most recent code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your articles don't get a chance to load before you try accessing them. Which explains why it works when you debug it step-by-step - they have more time to load.

Answer (score 0):

When you run across an error like you describe in the subject line, it's often because of a timing issue - some long-running code isn't finishing before execution gets to a later section of code that needs its results. In this case, it looks to be due to a network request that you're making and expecting results from nearly instantaneously. You'll need to move that request elsewhere.